# Notify viewmodel that model has changed (from combobox)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have one model that implements INotifyPropertyChanged through BaseModel class.
It has other model as element inside of it.

```
class SIDPoslJavnaUstanova : BaseModel
{
    private int? _sid_posl_javna_ustanova_id;
    ...
    private decimal? _udaljenost;
    private SIDJavnaUstanova _sid_javna_ustanova;

    public SIDJavnaUstanova SidJavnaUstanova
    {
        get { return _sid_javna_ustanova; }
        set {
            if (_sid_javna_ustanova != value)
            {
                _sid_javna_ustanova = value;
                if (_sid_javna_ustanova != null)
                {
                    _sid_javna_ustanova_id = _sid_javna_ustanova.SidJavnaUstanovaId;
                }
                else
                {
                    _sid_javna_ustanova_id = null;
                }
                RaisePropertyChanged("SidJavnaUstanova");
            }
        }
    }
```

I have viewmodel that has observable collection of this model objects.

```
class BaseViewModel<T> : ObservableObject
{
    private ObservableCollection<T> _elements = new ObservableCollection<T>();
    public ObservableCollection<T> Elements  
    ...

   class SIDPoslJavnaUstanovaViewModel : BaseViewModel<SIDPoslJavnaUstanova>
   {
   }
}
```

And finally, mainviewmodel that is bound to view:

```
class MainViewModel : BaseViewModel<Store>
{
   private SIDJavnaUstanovaViewModel _sidJavnaUstanovaViewModel;
   private SIDJavnaUstanova _sidJavnaUstanova;

    public SIDPoslJavnaUstanovaViewModel SidPoslJavnaUstanovaViewModel
    {
        get { return _sidPoslJavnaUstanovaViewModel; }
        set
        {
            if (_sidPoslJavnaUstanovaViewModel != value)
            {
                _sidPoslJavnaUstanovaViewModel = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("SidPoslJavnaUstanovaViewModel");
            }
        }
    }

    public SIDJavnaUstanovaViewModel SidJavnaUstanovaViewModel
    {
        get { return _sidJavnaUstanovaViewModel; }
        set
        {
            if (_sidJavnaUstanovaViewModel != value)
            { 
                _sidJavnaUstanovaViewModel = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("SidJavnaUstanovaViewModel");

            }
        }
    }
```

SidJavnaUstanova is only used to populate combobox, and to bind to object when choosen.

I have combobox in datagrid, that has mulitple lines. Element is SIDJAVNAUSTANOVA , and dropdown is SIDJAVNAUSTANOVAVIEWMODEL.
Dropdown is SIDJAVNAUSTANOVAVIEWMODEL.ELEMENTS
(cannot show you picture not enough reputation)

```
<src:BaseWindow.Resources>
    <viewmod:MainViewModel  x:Key="StoreViewM"/>
</src:BaseWindow.Resources>
<DataGrid.Columns>
<DataGridTemplateColumn  Width="140" Header="{StaticResource name}">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
  <DataTemplate>
<ComboBox  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SidJavnaUstanovaViewModel.Elements,
Source={StaticResource StoreViewM}}" 
SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SidJavnaUstanova,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, 
Mode=TwoWay}" 
DisplayMemberPath="Naziv" 
SelectedValue="{Binding Path=SidJavnaUstanova, Mode=TwoWay}">
</ComboBox>
...
```

Everything is working fine except when combobox is changed, element SIDJavnaUstanova of object  SIDPoslJavnaUstanova is changed, and I can catch this in its model property. But what I must have, is to catch change of this SidJavnaUstanova in viewmodel, so I can implement check-out if there are duplicates of sidjavnaustanova in sidposljavnaustanovaviewmodel.elements. I cannot realize how to do that. 
Something like

```
SIDPoslJavnaUstanova.Elements.??? SIDJavnaUstanova
```

I cannot do this because elements is observable collection.
Maybe it is a bad model, please suggest something or help with current code.

Comment: Why do you have two different base class for model and ViewModel? Since both shall be able to notify changes, why don't you let them derive from the same class? And please don't do this CapsLock thing, use code highlighting via ` instead.

Comment: They are pretty much the same, BaseModel has some property that I need later, but in base they are the same

Comment: Post image url in a comment and I'll add it to the question.

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/rZtGO.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to a) specify source for `SelectedItem` b) bind `SelectedItem` to the property of the same type, as elements in your collection (i.e. `SIDPoslJavnaUstanova` in your case).
This should work, i guess:

```
<ComboBox  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SidJavnaUstanovaViewModel.Elements,
    Source={StaticResource StoreViewM}}" 
    SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedModel,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, 
    Mode=TwoWay, Source={StaticResource StoreViewM}}" 
    DisplayMemberPath="Naziv">
</ComboBox>

.........................................

//MainViewModel

public SIDPoslJavnaUstanova SelectedModel
{
    get { return _selectedModel; }
    set
    {
        if (_selectedModel != value)
        { 
            _selectedModel = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedModel");

        }
    }
}
```

And yes, this is some awful design.

Comment: If you have some suggestions about design, please tell me because this is my first MVVM. But SelectedItem cannot be type of SidPoslJavnaUstanova because it's a type of SidJavnaUstanova.

Comment: @DukeNukem Sadly, i cant suggest you a course of action without knowing what you are trying to do. But from the looks of it your logical hierarchy is broken. If your data grid represents differnt stores, you shoud probably incapsulate your `SIDPoslJavnaUstanovaViewModel` (and similar properties) into `Store` object, for example, instead of keeping it in the main view model

Comment: Store model has some basic data, like address, city, name but SidPoslJavnaUstanova is different table with many records for one store. I have many of those tables that has one-to-many relationship, I do not want them all in Store model, or maybe I want?

Comment: It seems it is working ! I didn't get it at the same moment. Thanks :) Of course, it is SIDJavnaUstanova not SIDPoslJavnaUstanova but I manage to get it with     `set {_sidPoslJavnaUstanovaViewModel.SelectedElement.SidJavnaUstanova = value;}`